# How to turn off notifications from Facebook Messenger on Android Gingerbread?

Tags: notifications, facebook

All the instructions on the web for disabling messenger notifications are for Androids 4.0 and higher. I just don't have "show notifications" box which to uncheck in the app menu on my Gingerbread device. Is there any other way to turn off messenger notifications or am I simply forced to buy a new phone?

Thanks a lot!

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Those instructions are for Android 4.1 or higher, because this option was introduced with 4.1 – so before, there is no "common way" to do that. Either *the app* supports it – or not. No system-wide option for that before 4.1.

Comment: Messenger is good app for those who really don't want to miss any notification. If you don't want it, uninstall it and look for alternatives like Nimbuzz, IM+, etc... There are so many alternatives which supports Facebook chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [root](/questions/tagged/root) access on your device, an application [like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff&hl=en) may work for you. I cannot test it as I have no Gingerbread devices.

---

This option only lets you turn off notifications for 24 hours (what a terrible feature)

Open the messenger application.

Go to the 'cog' icon for settings.

Turn notifications off.

This image shows the Icon, and shows the 'Notifications' option, but the arrow isn't pointing to it!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort, but this doesn't quite address my problem. That option lets me turn off notifications for the next 24 hrs max. I would like it to be permanently disabled.

Comment: @Toolik that's a rubbish feature! I've never used it myself, and didn't realise it did that. Facebook seem to assume you always want their notifications. If you turn off Light, Vibration, Sound, Notification Preview, Chat Heads, is there anything left for it to notify with? I'll keep looking. I, personally, would not use any app that doesn't let me turn off notifications permanently, but I get that you probably don't want to get rid of it. Root access may allow you to do this.

Comment: @Toolik no problem, I also updated the answer for root users. If it works, consider accepting the answer! I'm still amazed how badly designed the whole app is!